How do I terminate unused differential line driver pins properly?
I have an SN65LVDS1050PW and a DS90LV031ATMTC. Both components have only one driver in use so I was wondering how to properly externally terminate the unused input and output pins of the left over drivers? I couldn't find anything about floating/unused pins in their datasheets. If an example schematic was included in an answer, that would be appreciated!
SN65LVDS1050PW datasheet
DS90LV031ATMTC datasheet

For the SN65LVDS1050PW, the data sheet shows equivalent input circuits: -

As can be seen there are 300 kΩ resistors employed that set the input default level when the pin is unused. You won't need to do anything with the output pins; they will be what they will be.
For the DS90LV031ATMTC it has CMOS inputs that should be connected to an appropriate logic level.

Ah, I missed those 300k resistors in those equivalent circuits, thank you! For DS90LV031ATMTC, If I pull the unused CMOS inputs down is it still better to have a termination resistor of say 100 ohm between the + and - outputs instead of leaving them floating?

@Nick No need. They should not be switching so “terminating” them will have no effect.

@Nick if we are done here, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.
